# colores exactos en grafico de libreria MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

Tags: android-studio

hola estoy utilizando la esta librería en android

**implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'**

y tengo una de las dudas quizá mas simples como puedo ponerle colores exactos a este tipo de grafica por ejemplo verde y rojo para que sea mas sencillo de entender el ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi XML esta definido asi:

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
                    android:id="@+id/chartPagos"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="267dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="7dp" />
```

en código realmente no tengo nada diferente a los ejemplos que he visto solo  estoy enviando los datos directo a la gráfica y la genero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas ejecutar la función setColors en el objeto PieDataSet. Le puedes pasar un ArrayList con los códigos de los colores. Te asigna un color para cada elemento según estén ordenados los elementos de este array. Si le pasas menos colores que elementos, cuando se le acabe el array de colores, volverá a empezar repitiendo colores.

Tienes un ejemplo en [MPAndroidChart-PieChartActitivy](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java)

En ese ejemplo está incluyendo en el array todos los colores que hay para que no se repitan nunca.